# Elasticsearch dsl deleting error

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a problem with deleting items using elasticsearch dsl. When i trying to filter my data it goes easily and something like this works great.

```
def searchId(fileId):
s = Search().filter('term', fileId=fileId)
# for hit in s:
#     print(str(hit.foreignKey))
response=s.execute()
# print(response.hits.total)
return response
```

Scanning works also :

```
def scanning():
s = Search()
i = 0
for hit in s.scan():
    if hit.domain == 'Messages':
        i+=1
        print(str(hit.fileId) + " : " + str(hit.domain) + " : " + str(i))
```

But when i wanna to delete items like this :

```
def deleteId(fileId):
s = Search().query('match', fileId=fileId)
response = s.delete()
return "Done"
```

I got an error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/home/o.solop/DataSearchEngine/datasearch/elasticapp/search.py", line 96, in deleteId
    response = s.delete()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/search.py", line 660, in delete
    **self._params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 73, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 887, in delete_by_query
    raise ValueError("Empty value passed for a required argument.")
ValueError: Empty value passed for a required argument.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I missed an index in the Search constructor. I should do something like:

```
def deleteId(fileId):
 s = Search(index='my_index_name').query('match', fileId=fileId)
 response = s.delete()
```

`Elasticsearch-dsl` uses the delete_by_query API, as indicated in my error message, which needs to know which index to perform the delete against.